# meaning of the verb "model" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here it goes:

> Person 1 - How can I get my partner to respect me?
>
> Person 2 - **Model** what that looks like by respecting yourself.

I suspect it might mean *copy* something, but then, as the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/model) says, it should be *copy oneself on*.

Comment: Your suspicion involves the reflexive verb, **to model oneself on**. But here the verb is transitive.

Comment: I'm curious why you always seem to start your questions with *Here it goes:*.

Comment: Jason: I guess it is a good way to indicate that I am going to give the sentences wherein I came across a phrase or word I don't understand. Could you please tell me if there is something wrong with it? Could tell me a better way to do it?

Comment: We don't know what **it** is in "Here it goes". Are you making these sentences up? Are you quoting something you've heard or read?

Comment: Mostly I have heard or read those sentences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Model X* as a verb is like a lot of other "verb-ified" nouns, it means *make a model of X*.

If X is not a physical thing, means "show how it's done properly by doing it", or "leading by example."; synonymous somewhat with *demonstrate*.

Answer (score 1):

There the transitive verb **model** would mean "to exemplify, to show by action or demeanor".

P.S. Used in this way the verb is popular psychology jargon.